# Airflow seems to be ignoring "fernet_key" config

Tags: airflow

**Summary:** Ariflow seems to ignore `fernet_key` value both from `airflow.cfg` and environment variables, even though the exposed config in the webserver GUI shows the correct value. All DAGs using encrypted variables therefore fail.

Now the details:

I have an Airflow 2.3.2 (webserver and scheduler) running on a VM (Ubuntu 20.04) in the cloud. To start and restart the services I am using `systemctl`. Here are the contents of the `airflow-webserver.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service airflow-init.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/airflow/secrets.txt
Environment="AIRFLOW_HOME=/etc/airflow"
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
RuntimeDirectory=airflow
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can tell I am using an environment file. It looks like this:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=some value
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__SECRET_KEY=some value
```

The setup itself seems to be working as confirmed by an exposed config in the webserver GUI:
[link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqufL.png).

However, since upgrading to 2.3.2 (from 2.2.3) I am facing an issue that seems to be related with the fernet key configuration. The gist of it is that airflow seems to ignore the `fernet_key` config and therefore fails to decode variables. This is how it manifests:

```
$ airflow variables get DBT_USER
Variable DBT_USER does not exist
$ airflow variables list -v
[2022-07-14 17:57:09,920] {variable.py:79} ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=DBT_USER, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
[2022-07-14 17:57:09,922] {variable.py:79} ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=DBT_PASSWORD, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
[2022-07-14 17:57:09,924] {variable.py:79} ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=DBT_USER, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
[2022-07-14 17:57:09,925] {variable.py:79} ERROR - Can't decrypt _val for key=DBT_PASSWORD, FERNET_KEY configuration missing
key         
============
DBT_USER    
DBT_PASSWORD
```

I receive exactly the same error running the DAGs which use encrypted variables (templated or with `Variable.get`). The issue persists even if I hardcode the `fernet_key` in `airflow.cfg`. Since I have not too many variables I tried deleting them and creating new ones to ensure that `fernet_key` matches the key needed to decode values stored in the database. Then I confirmed that the `fernet_key` from my config can correctly decode the values stored in the db (I fetched encrypted values by querying `variable` table in the PostgreSQL directly).

I am out of ideas so any hint is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the exposed configuration in the webserver the same as that in the scheduler and worker services?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Yes, I just double checked that and also (just in case) made sure that there are no stray `airflow.cfg` files somewhere else in the system

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check cryptography, make sure:

1. package version according to airflow and python constraint txt file
2. package location, maybe your package is installed under `/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` path and corrupted, shadow the package under `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` package, you need to remove/uninstall corrupted one.

I met the same thing, after remove the corrupted one and restart webserver &scheduler, the error disappeared.